# regex - how to select first item from list

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

help! I dont have any knowledge about regex but I need to use it in my sql query (amazon redshift). I have list like this: [1245,2324,4433] and I would like to get first number (1245). How can I do that?

regards

Comment: Try `regexp(col, '\\d+')`

Answer (score 1):

```
select (regexp_matches('[1245,2324,4433]', '\d+'))[1]
```

Explanation: with `regexp_matches` you select the first number from the string (`\d+`) then you select the first (and the only) element from a returned set.

If no number found at all 0 rows would be returned.

For RDS it would be

```
regexp_substr('[12456,232466,4433]','\\d+')
```

References:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html

Comment: I got an error: [42883][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: function regexp_matches("unknown", "unknown") does not exist; java.lang.RuntimeException: com.amazon.support.exceptions.ErrorException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: function regexp_matches("unknown", "unknown") does not exist;

Comment: @monika_w091 then try `regexp_substr` instead https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html

Comment: select (regexp_substr('[1245,2324,4433]', '\d+')), result: empty row

Comment: select (regexp_substr('[12456,232466,4433]','[^,]*')), result : [12456, how to delete "[" ?

Comment: @monika_w091 try to use the `\\d+` regexp instead

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
select replace(split_part('[1245,2324,4433]',',',1),'[','')
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19175172)

Comment: @GreatBigBore what do you mean? I don't need clarification, this snippet solves to problem of getting the first element from provided string on Amazon Redshift

Comment: That message is auto-generated by the review system; not all of it applies to you. The main problem is that a real answer doesn't start with "you can try". Also, the system is always suspicious of short answers, which draws more reviewers, which might get your question deleted. If you can think of any useful information to add, add it. But not filler! Good luck.